# Need way to display iPhone addressbook contacts

Tags: uitableview, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I have been following many examples to add addressbook functionality to one of my views. 
I am getting stumbled between Addressbook API, ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and how to fit them into UITableView. I am highly confused as to what all controls I need to put over my storyboard to get the whole thing working.

What I need is:

- Last Name First Name (in table view display) along with an image icon (same for all contacts)
- Phone Number (needed but not necessarily to be displayed)
- When single cell is clicked, it should present a popover that offers certain number of options in a popup menu (but contacts table view should not disappear with the popover)

Can anyone point me exact example that achieves this?
XCode steps that can optionally achieve would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are a little confused with how the AddressBook API works.

There's an apple developer reference that have a good example of how you can use the API.

I have linked it here [Apple QuickContact Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Listings/Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m.html)

In summary, you can preload certain data that you are keen to display on your tableview into NSArray. Then upon UITableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` call the respective method to push the another viewcontroller to display.

Hope that clears up your doubt.